# ractive array is changing, but not computed value

Tags: ractivejs

I use an array of objects as data for my ractive component (received from a PouchDB) which needs filtering inside ractive for the proper output. But anything I tried - even if the data - referred to as "docs" is changed correctly, the filtered aka computed values stay the same.

I tried with method:

```
 new Ractive({
        el: '#container',
        template: Listing,
        magic: true,
        modifyArrays: true,
        data: {docs},
        computed: {
            List: function(){
                let tempList = [];
                for(var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
                    if (docs[i].specificValue == otherValue)  {
                        let newValue = docs[i];
                        tempList.push(newValue);
                    }
                }
                return tempList;
                }
            }
    });
```

with a helper object

```
Ractive.defaults.data.helper = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
            if (docs[i].specificValue == otherValue) {
                return docs[i].whatever ;
            }
        }
    }
 new Ractive({
        el: '#container',
        template: '{{helper()}}',
        magic: true,
        modifyArrays: true,
        data: {List: docs}
    });
```

and a data function as described in [Ractive computed property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582912/ractive-computed-property)

But nothing worked the way expected. When I use docs directly the binding works as expected.

PS: the code may look a bit awkward because I just copied and simplified.

Comment: Can you provide a simple, reproducible demo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ractive [relies on the presence of `this.get()`](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/computed-properties#computed-properties-to-the-rescue) to know which data a computation depends upon.

> With this, the area property can be treated like any other. It will update reactively (because the calls to ractive.get() tell Ractive that it should be recomputed when width or height change), so you can do...

In your example, you are accessing `docs` directly. Ractive will not be aware that `docs` is a dependency of `List`.

Here's a comparative example of a list using `this.get()` vs one that does not:

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3];

new Ractive({
  el: 'body',
  template: `
   <div>Working: {{# workingList }}{{.}}{{/}}</div>
   <div>Not working: {{# nonWorkingList }}{{.}}{{/}}</div>
  `,
  magic: true,
  modifyArrays: true,
  data: {
    list: arr
  },
  computed: {
    workingList() {
      return this.get('list').map(n => `#${n}`);
    },
    nonWorkingList() {
      return arr.map(n => `#${n}`)
    }
  }
});

setInterval(() => {
  arr.push(arr.length);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ractive@0.8.9/ractive.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, That made it more clear to me, but I still don't get it to work. Seems like I'm missing some fundamental point. I've managed to set up a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s94t0tke/14/) where `this.get()` is used - the docs are filtered and rendered, but not the update.

Comment: @Torf Updated the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s94t0tke/16/). You don't access the array directly (as `doc`). You need to retrieve it _from Ractive_ (via `this.get(stringKeypath)`). See comments for changes.